# cordova.exec callbacks not called

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I'm new to Cordova and trying to create a fairly basic Android plugin.

When I call one of the JavaScript functions, e.g.

```js
window.MyPlugin.getAdvertisingId().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Nothing happens. Neither the success nor error callbacks are called. I added some logging to `MyPlugin.execute` and monitored it in `logcat`. It wasn't logged, which means it's never called.

The callbacks are piling up in the `cordova.callbacks` object (in JavaScript), suggesting they're pending some response that never arrives.

In `logcat`, I see this message immediately when I make one of these calls from JavaScript:

```
CordovaBridge: Ignoring exec() from previous page load.
```

So it's telling me that it's ignoring these `cordova.exec` calls, but not why.

This is using the latest Cordova, running on an Amazon Fire TV Stick 4K Max.

plugin.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin
    xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="cordova-plugin-mycompany"
    version="0.0.0"
>
    <name>MyCompany Plugin</name>
    <description>MyCompany Android plugin</description>
    <license>Apache 2.0</license>
    <keywords>cordova,mycompany</keywords>
    <js-module src="www/myPlugin.js" name="myPlugin">
        <clobbers target="MyPlugin" />
    </js-module>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="myPlugin">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.mycompany.cordova.plugin.MyPlugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/MyPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/mycompany/cordova/plugin" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

src/android/MyPlugin.java:

```java
package com.mycompany.cordova.plugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        // Implementation omitted, because this is never called.
    }
}
```

www/myPlugin.js

```js
exec = require('cordova/exec');

function getAdvertisingId() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(
            resolve,
            reject,
            'myPlugin',
            'getAdvertisingId',
            []
        );
    });
}

module.exports = {
    getAdvertisingId,
};
```

Comment: Are you waiting for device ready ?

Comment: @Eric yes I am. The `deviceready` event is firing.

Comment: I gave up on Cordova and built an app containing only a `WebView`, using Android Studio. It's _much_ easier than Cordova.